# Remove substring if exists

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have 3 possible input cases

```
string input = "";        // expected result: ""
string input = "bar-foo"; // expected result: "foo"
string input = "foo";     // expected result: "foo"
```

And I have to remove everyting including the first separator char `-` *if exists*.

Working approach:

```
string output = input.Split('-').LastOrDefault();
```

I want to solve this without `Split()` - my NOT working approach:

```
string output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('-') );
```

How can I handle the `IndexOutOfRangeException` / make this code work?

Comment: Any reason not to just check the value of `input.IndexOf('-')` before using it?

Comment: @Chris it's not required - see Dmitry Bychenko's answer

Comment: While its not required that doesn't mean it isn't reasonable to use it. I was wondering if there were specific requirements that you were missing out that made this obvious solution unacceptable. For example checking the value of `input.IndexOf('-')` could result in not doing an unnecessary call to `Substring` (though it is quite possible that Substring is optimised for the situation when you just pass it 0 so this isn't a big deal).Essentially if I see a question where there seems to be an "obvious" solution I like to check whether this solution was just less obvious to others or invalid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add `1`:

```
string output = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf('-') + 1);
```

If there's no `-` in the `input`, `LastIndexOf` returns `-1` and so you'll have the *entire string*.

I've assumed that your are looking for `input`'s *suffix*, that's why I've put `LastIndexOf`:

```
"123-456-789" -> "789"
```

If you want to cut off the *prefix*:

```
"123-456-789" -> "456-789"
```

please, change  `LastIndexOf` into `IndexOf`

Comment: To remove the separator(if available) + 1 was needed anyway, so this fixes both issues

Answer (score 1):

Why not just remove it from the string without checking:

```
input = input.Replace("-foo", string.Empty);
```

Comment: because that was just a sample

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use `Contains` Method to identify **-** is available or not.

```
string a = "";

    if (a.Contains("-"))
    {
       string output = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf('-') + 1);
    }
```